# .animate() and scale function

Tags: jquery, methods, gallery, jquery-animate, image-scaling

I need to create a gallery that depends on several factors and performs a series of images scaled to fit. Anyway, I need that when you click on a "trigger" button main container occupies almost the entire visible area of the viewport and the images it contains respectable scale if ratio.

I am following this [reference](http://bit.ly/salu6A)

The behavior that I can not do is to enlarge the image. When you click on one of them the thumbs disappear and the main image is scaled. This my code is as follows:

The function I use to enlarge the images I do based on a small article I read about the jQuery .animate() method.

```
function resize(){ 
gallery = $('#items'); 
galleryH = gallery.height(); 

$('#items img').each(function() { 
    var height = $(this).height(); 
    $(this).stop(true).animate({'height':galleryH},1000); 
    }); 
} 
resize();
```

According to this method "animating" only the height, the width is automatically thereby maintaining the ratio. This seems to work properly. As you see above is scaled according to the height of its container.

Well, this works well when the page loads and when scaling the size of the window. Then I need is that when you click on the container or other button/firer fills the window, similar to what happens in the example attached, and images are scaled according to this size. As in the example. To do this use the following code:

```
function changeView(){ 

    if(gallery.hasClass("largeExp")){ 
        gallery.removeClass("largeExp"); 
            gallery.stop(true).animate({'height':'200px'},500); 
            console.log("Normal Mode"); 
        } 
        else{ 
            gallery.addClass("largeExp"); 
            gallery.stop(true).animate({'height':'650px'},500); 
            console.log("Expand Mode"); 
        } 

        console.log("Now would launch resize()"); 
        resize(); 
} 

$('#items').click(function() { 
    changeView(); 
});
```

Well, what happens is that the gallery (the container) actually "animate" to such measures but no images contained within. The resize() method, only begins to run from the second click. In the first click is great and scales as I need, in the second click images are scaled to the large size while the gallery (the container) moves to small or normal mode. From here the container and the images scales in a inverse way. When the container is in normal mode the images are in expanded and so. Working so the gallery (container) and images never fit. I need that when container is to expanded the images go to expanded too.

I have not really experience in JS and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. So I hope you can help me, I've lost a lot of hours with this!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am on my iPad right now so I can't really replicate the code but all I can say for now is that it seems like a timing issue. What happens is you click the button to scale the gallery, the resize function is called practically at the same time the animation to scale the gallery which takes 500 ms is launched. You need to either set a time out of greater that 500 ms on the resize function or call the function inside of the animate method. Basically you have to call the resize function after the gallery rescaling is complete.

```
setTimeout(function() { resize(); }, 510);
```

Comment: Hi Yura! Looks to be something related with you are telling. I tested this solution and works correctly, but I need that the animation of the container and the animation of the content (the images) occur at the same time in order to get a smooth scale effect of both elements. How could I to launch the both functions at the same time? Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Nobody has idea of how getting to work this? I really don´t undersand why functions doesn´t run sequentially in order I launch them and they need to have these intervals.

Comment: Oh ok i got you. I'll help you out tomorrow once I get next to a computer

Comment: Wow, that would be great! I´m testing now with queues in order to get some control with the sequences, but I have not good results by now :(